# Is there any way to cast Json Object in angular

Tags: json, angular

Able to receive response from server as a JSON object.Tried to cast JSON object to emp (type Employee),but not happening. What is the problem with my code?? Is there another way to solve this??

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'httpClientProject';

  posts : JsonGet[];
  emp : Employee;

  constructor(private appService : AppService,private employeeService : EmployeeService){}

ngOnInit(){
  this.getData();
  this.getEmployee();
console.log(this.emp)  }

getData() : void{
  this.appService.getData().subscribe(posts=>(this.posts = posts));   }

getEmployee() : void{
   this.employeeService.getEmployee().subscribe(data=>this.emp={...data});   }   }
```

employee.service.ts

```
export class EmployeeService {

    private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/SpringRestWebService/getSingleEmployye';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

     getEmployee(): Observable<Employee> {
             return this.http.get<Employee>(this.baseUrl);  }   }
```

Employee.ts

```
export class Employee {

    public id: number;
    public name: string;
    public city: string;

    constructor(id:number, name:string, status:string) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.city = status;    }     }


Json Response From Server

{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "asdasd",
    "city": "Hasdasdayd"
}
```

Comment: `this.emp={...data});` You don't need to destructure it here.

Comment: even this.emp=data is not working

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Comment: when i try to print emp in console it say emp is undefined

Comment: Where are you printing it? `.subscribe(data => { this.emp=data; console.log(this.emp}); } }`

Comment: i did a mistake...tried to do this ( console.log(this.emp}) outside of subscribe

Answer (score -1):

```
 Just define type when passing variable in subscribe 
   getEmployee() : void{
       this.employeeService.getEmployee().subscribe((data:Employee)=>{
          this.emp=data;
}  
}
```